# In how many ways I can put $2$ red balls and $3$ green balls in $5$ boxes?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, balls-in-bins

I have $5(N)$ boxes and some balls. Here's the description:
Red Balls $= 2 (k1 = 2)$
Green Balls $= 3 (k2 = 3)$

```
    --------------------------
    |    |    |    |    |    |
    --------------------------
```

How many ways do I have to put in these balls in the five boxes? 
(The boxes are labeled/ordered)

p.s. One box can hold only one ball

Comment: How many balls should be in each box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the solution, we assume that a box can contain any number of balls.

You are probably familiar with the [*Stars and Bars*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) way of counting the number of ways to put $2$ red balls in $5$ boxes.

If so, you also can find the number of ways to put $3$ blue balls in $5$ boxes.

Multiply.

**Remark:** $1.$ If *Stars and Bars* is not familiar, one can make it familiar (the Wikipedia article cited is pretty clear). Or else one can count separately, by considering cases, the answers to the $2$ ball problem and the $3$ ball problem.

$2.$ If we are to have $1$ ball per box (this was not specified), then the number of ways is the number of ways to choose where the red balls will go. This is $\binom{5}{2}$.

Comment: Yup, 1 ball per box. Thanks!

Actually I had to use it as a part of a larger problem. The task was to find out how many anagrams of a word are Palindromes.

Thanks again!

Comment: OK. If you need a check of that answer, please leave a message. Will not be able to reply immediately, but within a couple of hours.